# Best method to estimate the mean of a normal distribution?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator, posterior

Let $X = ( x_1, ..., x_n ) $ be $n$ samples from a normal distribution with unknown mean.
What is the best estimator for this mean?

I can think of at least 2 unbiased estimators:

- The empirical mean $ \hat \mu_1 = \frac{\sum_i x_i }{n} $
- A bayesian approach $ \hat \mu_2 = E[ P( \theta | X ) ] $, where $ P( \theta | X ) $ is the posterior distribution over the mean. The prior distribution over the mean is $ \cal N ( m, s^2) $ for some meta parameters $(m, s^2)$.

Are there other biased or unbiased estimators for this problem? Which one is the best?

Comment: The [trimmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator) and [winsorized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising) mean are pretty popular in robust statistics.

Comment: $\hat\mu=X_1$ is an unbiased estimator. The estimator $\hat\mu=7$, though biased, can perform better than the sample mean under some circumstances. Nevertheless the sample mean has the advantage of being the uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator & the maximum-likelihood estimator of the mean for a normal population, which is why alternatives are only used in practice when the normality assumption is doubted.

Comment: And note that the Bayesian estimator you give is only asymptotically unbiased - though that's hardly a concern.